Tkinter rows collapsing tic-tac-toe
Have worked with a friend through the tutorial for creating a tic-tac-toe game in Tkinter. We extended it to work for a 4x4 grid and wanted instead of using X's and O's to import our own custom images. We've managed to reconfigure the code that allows these images to be inserted when a grid square is clicked but we can't work out why whenever a row or column is filled, it will collapse it down (whereas we want it to remain the same size). Is there a way so it keeps all the cells the same size throughout?
https://realpython.com/tic-tac-toe-python/
import tkinter as tk #Currently 8.6
from tkinter import font
from itertools import cycle
from typing import NamedTuple

class Player(NamedTuple):
    # How to do as a 3D shape rather than flat shape
    label: str
    image: tk.PhotoImage
    color: str

class Move(NamedTuple):
    row: int
    col: int
    label: str = ""

#root = tk.Tk()
BOARD_SIZE = 4
#Need to change default player - technically one person doesn't have label

    
class TicTacToeGame:
    def __init__(self, board_size=BOARD_SIZE):
        self.board_size = board_size
        self.winner_combo = []
        self._current_moves = []
        self._has_winner = False
        self._winning_combos = []
        self._setup_board()
    
    def _setup_board(self):
        self._current_moves = [
            [Move(row, col) for col in range(self.board_size)]
            for row in range(self.board_size)
        ]
        self._winning_combos = self._get_winning_combos()
        
    def _get_winning_combos(self):
        rows = [
            [(move.row, move.col) for move in row]
            for row in self._current_moves
        ]
        columns = [list(col) for col in zip(*rows)]
        first_diagonal = [row[i] for i, row in enumerate(rows)]
        second_diagonal = [col[j] for j, col in enumerate(reversed(columns))]
        return rows + columns + [first_diagonal, second_diagonal]
    
    def is_valid_move(self, move):
        """Return True if move is valid, and False otherwise."""
        row, col = move.row, move.col
        move_was_not_played = self._current_moves[row][col].label == ""
        no_winner = not self._has_winner
        return no_winner and move_was_not_played
    
    def process_move(self, move):
        """Process the current move and check if it's a win."""
        row, col = move.row, move.col
        self._current_moves[row][col] = move
        for combo in self._winning_combos:
            #Set logic may not work for ours
            # [1,1,0,0], [0,1,0,1],...
            # Sum the arrays in the line
            # Check for any element being 0 or 4 (min/max statement on array)
            # Pascal 1,4,6,4,1 in terms of shared attributes (0 up to 4)
            results = set(
                self._current_moves[n][m].label
                for n, m in combo
            )
            is_win = (len(results) == 1) and ("" not in results)
            if is_win:
                self._has_winner = True
                self.winner_combo = combo
                break
                
    def has_winner(self):
        """Return True if the game has a winner, and False otherwise."""
        return self._has_winner
    
    def is_tied(self):
        """Return True if the game is tied, and False otherwise."""
        no_winner = not self._has_winner
        played_moves = (
            # Has the label of every cell been updated from empty i.e. piece played
            move.label for row in self._current_moves for move in row
        )
        return no_winner and all(played_moves)

    def reset_game(self):
        """Reset the game state to play again."""
        for row, row_content in enumerate(self._current_moves):
            for col, _ in enumerate(row_content):
                row_content[col] = Move(row, col)
        self._has_winner = False
        self.winner_combo = []

class TicTacToeBoard(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("TicTacToe Game")
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file="pieces/cyan_cuboid_small_striped.png").subsample(5)
        img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="pieces/orange_cuboid_small_striped.png").subsample(5)
        players = (
            Player(label="X", image = img, color="blue"),
            Player(label="O", image = img2, color="green"),
        )
        self._players = cycle(players)
        self._cells = {}
        self._game = game
        self.current_player = next(self._players)
        self._create_menu()
        self._create_board_display()
        self._create_board_grid()
        

    def _create_board_display(self):
        display_frame = tk.Frame(master=self)
        display_frame.pack(fill=tk.X) #frame fills width if window resized
        self.display = tk.Label(
              master=display_frame, #label needs to live in frame
              text="Ready?",
              font=font.Font(size=28, weight="bold"),
        )
        self.display.pack()

    def _create_board_grid(self):
        grid_frame = tk.Frame(master=self) #Hold the game grid cells
        grid_frame.pack()
        for row in range(self._game.board_size):
            self.rowconfigure(row, weight=1, minsize=50)
            self.columnconfigure(row, weight=1, minsize=75)
            for col in range(self._game.board_size):
                button = tk.Button(
                    master=grid_frame,
                    text="",
                    font=font.Font(size=36, weight="bold"),
                    fg="black",
                    width=3,
                    height=2,
                    highlightbackground="lightblue",
                )
                self._cells[button] = (row, col)
                button.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.play)
                button.grid(
                    row=row,
                    column=col,
                    padx=5,
                    pady=5,
                    sticky="nsew"
                )

    def toggle_player(self):
        """Return a toggled player."""
        self.current_player = next(self._players)
    
    # The .mainloop() method on the Tk class runs what’s known as the application’s 
    # main loop or event loop. This is an infinite loop in which all the GUI events happen.
    def play(self, event):
        """Handle a player's move."""
        clicked_btn = event.widget
        row, col = self._cells[clicked_btn]
        move = Move(row, col, self.current_player.label)
        if self._game.is_valid_move(move): # Maybe show error message to user if False?
            self._update_button(clicked_btn)
            self._game.process_move(move)
            # Maybe check winner first rather than tied
            # Maybe only check winner after row/col/diagonal was filled
            # Technically first board_size - 1 moves don't need check
            if self._game.is_tied():
                self._update_display(msg="Tied game!", color="red")
            elif self._game.has_winner():
                self._highlight_cells()
                msg = f'Player "{self.current_player.label}" won!'
                color = self.current_player.color
                self._update_display(msg, color)
            else:
                self.toggle_player()
                msg = f"{self.current_player.label}'s turn"
                self._update_display(msg)
                
    def _update_button(self, clicked_btn):
        # Need to set to a 3D image for us
        clicked_btn.config(image=self.current_player.image)
        #clicked_btn.config(text=self.current_player.label)
        #clicked_btn.config(fg=self.current_player.color)
        
    def _update_display(self, msg, color="black"):
        self.display["text"] = msg
        self.display["fg"] = color
        
    def _highlight_cells(self):
        for button, coordinates in self._cells.items():
            if coordinates in self._game.winner_combo:
                button.config(highlightbackground="red")
                
    def _create_menu(self):
        menu_bar = tk.Menu(master=self)
        self.config(menu=menu_bar)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(master=menu_bar)
        file_menu.add_command(
            label="Play Again",
            command=self.reset_board
        )
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        
    def reset_board(self):
        """Reset the game's board to play again."""
        self._game.reset_game()
        self._update_display(msg="Ready?")
        # Reset all the buttons
        for button in self._cells.keys():
            button.config(highlightbackground="lightblue")
            button.config(text="")
            button.config(fg="black")



def main():
    """Create the game's board and run its main loop."""
    game = TicTacToeGame()
    board = TicTacToeBoard(game)
    board.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()




It is because you have set height=2.  When there is only text, it is in lines. But when image is used, it is in pixels.

Your code is working. The last image is not displayed. And the message displayed  X has won.

It is because you have set height=2 on those buttons. Note that when there is only text, it is by lines. However when image is used, it is by pixels.
So when there is one button not having image, the other buttons in the same row will be expanded to the same size of that button.  But when all buttons in the same row are using images, then the buttons will be shrink.
You can set the image option of those button to a blank image initially and set the width and height options to the desired size in pixels:
class TicTacToeBoard(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("TicTacToe Game")
        # create a blank image
        self.blank = tk.PhotoImage()
        ...

    def _create_board_grid(self):
        ...
        for row in range(self._game.board_size):
            ...
            for col in range(self._game.board_size):
                button = tk.Button(
                    master=grid_frame,
                    image=self.blank,  # use blank image
                    font=font.Font(size=36, weight="bold"),
                    fg="black",
                    width=100,    # set to desired size
                    height=100,
                    highlightbackground="lightblue",
                )
                ...
        ...


Not sure, but can you just write image=tk.PhotoImage() to avoid using a variable for the empty image?

@DanyaK Your suggestion may work, but it will create many instances of the images which is not necessary.

As far as I know, it won't create many instances. if you don't save the image in any variable, it will be deleted after creating a button. This can be checked by using self.image_names(). The list will always remain the same even after the images are “created”.

Thanks for your help - @DanyaK - found in particular your suggestion was very helpful!
